# Can't download file larger than 2 gb in MVC

Tags: c#, download

I want to download a zip file but its size is more than 2 gb. I am facing an problem due to the limitation of 2 gb size in byte[] array. How can I download the zip file?

```
FileContentResult fileContent = new 
FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(exportDirectoryZip), 
"application/zip")
{
    FileDownloadName = Path.GetFileName(exportDirectoryZip)
};



//FOR VIEWS
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    Inline = true,
    FileName = fileContent.FileDownloadName
};

//Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return File(fileContent.FileContents, "application/zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's terribly inefficent to load a large file (particularly 2GB) into memory that is merely being streamed to a client, not to mention that you run into memory issues on a 32-bit process.  You are much better off loading the file for streaming and returning the stream instead.  This lowers the memory impact of the host.

Comment: The last time I did something like that was in good old fashioned ASP.NET Web forms. HttpResponse.TransmitFile did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My files are stored in Azure blob which is more than 2gb. How to use the stream to read those files and download it to the client in zip format.

Comment: @Sameer You don’t.  You should be using Azure APIs

Comment: Thanks @MickyD let me do research on this on how to use Azure APIs.